# Add a button in the title bar in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a game as a school project with tkinter.I got a 800 lines long code, and I want to add a 4rd button in the title bar of one of my windows(not the main one). Is it possible and ,if yes, how can I manage to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to add buttons to the titlebar of a window in Tkinter.